# group samples based on shared mutations in a single multi samples vcf file

Tags: r, shell

I am learning about vcf file formatting and have a multi-sample (>300) vcf file and aim to **group** (take) **samples with shared mutations**.

Can someone suggest a tool/command/script solve this problem?

Comment: FYI: Cross posted on biostars (https://www.biostars.org/p/358896/)

Comment: @finswimmer Cross posting on biostars is alright.

Comment: @SmallChess I'm not against cross posting, but one should mention it, where they ask the question as well. Doing this every one can see if there is already a solution.

Comment: As I asked I am learning and asked for help :)

Comment: @finswimmer posted this response on Biostars `$ bcftools query -i 'GT="0/1"' -f '%CHROM\t%POS\t0/1\t%REF\t%ALT\t[%SAMPLE,]\n' input.vcf|sed 's/,$//'|awk -v OFS="\t" '{counts = split($6, samples, ","); print $1, $2, $3, counts, $4, $5, $6}' > stats_01.csv`

Comment: I think the question needs to be much more specific for that answer to be useful for anyone else. What does 'shared mutation mean'? What does 'group' them mean? I think a small sample of the input and desired output is needed.